# RED5 demos not working, caused by "scope not found"

Tags: ubuntu-14.04, red5

I am trying to run **RED5** (version 1.0.7) on **UBUNTU 14.04**, the server is working but all demos are broken. Most of them fail with a scope problem, example:

```
org.red5.server.net.rtmp.RTMPHandler - Scope bwcheck not found
```

I thing i need to modify something in the configuration, maybe in red5-web.xml as i see it an other post :

change

```
<bean id="web.scope" class="org.red5.server.scope.WebScope" init-method="register">
```

to

```
<bean id="web.scope" class="org.red5.server.WebScope" init-method="register">
```

Or should i move demos in an other place because the html files used are in `$RED5_HOME/webapps/root/demos`, but some parts of the demo seems to be located in  `$RED5_HOME/webapps` eg (chat, live, vod)
well i don't really know tomcat and the java logic but some help will really be welcome.

Thanks

***Log:***

```
[WARN] [RTMPConnectionExecutor-4] org.red5.server.net.rtmp.RTMPHandler - Scope not found
org.red5.server.exception.ScopeNotFoundException: Scope not found: bwcheck in null
    at org.red5.server.scope.ScopeResolver.resolveScope(ScopeResolver.java:112)
    at org.red5.server.Context.resolveScope(Context.java:158)
    at org.red5.server.net.rtmp.RTMPHandler.onCommand(RTMPHandler.java:323)
    at org.red5.server.net.rtmp.BaseRTMPHandler.messageReceived(BaseRTMPHandler.java:116)
    at org.red5.server.net.rtmp.ReceivedMessageTask.call(ReceivedMessageTask.java:72)
    at org.red5.server.net.rtmp.ReceivedMessageTask.call(ReceivedMessageTask.java:38)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
[INFO] [RTMPConnectionExecutor-4] org.red5.server.net.rtmp.RTMPHandler - Scope bwcheck not found on localhost
[WARN] [NioProcessor-14] org.red5.server.net.rtmp.RTMPMinaIoHandler - Destination connection was null, it is already disposed. Session id: DSNGKAODSPSGV
[INFO] [NioProcessor-14] org.red5.server.net.rtmp.RTMPMinaConnection - Connection is closed: DSNGKAODSPSGV
[WARN] [NioProcessor-14] org.red5.server.net.rtmp.RTMPMinaIoHandler - Connection was not found for DSNGKAODSPSGV
[INFO] [pool-4-thread-1] org.red5.server.tomcat.WarDeployer - Deploy wars with app start
[INFO] [pool-4-thread-1] org.red5.server.tomcat.WarDeployer - Deploy wars with app start
```

Comment: It seems that using RED-5 Pro solves my problems .... maybe open source versions need more skills and hacking ....

Answer (score 0):

In this case it probably means that you're missing the bwcheck app; by that I mean you should have a directory named bwcheck in red5/webapps and it should have various files in it, such as WEB-INF/red5-web.xml and WEB-INF/web.xml. If the files are there and its still not found, then the app didn't load / start for some reason; in that case you have to debug it by reading the logs and possibly increasing the log level.

Lastly, you should identify which version of Red5 you're using.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, i have updated the question with red5 Version, fyi, I have tried with RED5 1.0.7 & 1.0.6, i'am off since next Thursday, I will try your suggestions and post the results.